# Frame Video in Device Art from Android Studio Screen Record

Tags: android, video, android-studio

In Android Studio we can both capture and record screen on our devices. When capturing the screen we have the option to directly frame our screenshot in device art or use online tool http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html

**When Recording Screen there is no option to frame it in device art** and Google don't seem to provide any online option either.

What would be the fastest and easiest way for developers that want to showcase their screen recording in a frame from device art where a new video is created where device art is wrapped around our screen recording.

Give away your best tip. I would love a fast, free online service that solves this and guess there is one out there.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Indeed, such feature directly in Android Studio would be really great...

Comment: @BartoszOstrowski Did not find anything at the point when i was doing work in Android Studio, Maybe there is something now, it was a couple of months ago i did use it last, otherwise i guess the best solution is to record the video in Android studio and then use some video tool that allow you to put a frame around your video and from that compile one with the frame in it !

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a substantial amount of time researching, but could also not find a service for it.

I have however written a guide for how to record screen, add device frame and convert to gif, which you can find here:
http://appdictive.dk/blog/how-to/2015/04/20/google_plus_gif/

The short version of it is:

1. Record screen
2. [Get Device frame picture](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html)
3. Use Photoshop or other video editing software to add the frame as static picture to the video (guide briefly shows how to do this in Photoshop).

Hope this helps others searching for a solution to this as well.

Comment: Thanks for writing the tutorial. However i am not able to import the mp4 video in the Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you "Get Device frame picture"? Google's Device Art Generator only lets you download framed pictures, _not the empty frame itself_.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few services I've come across on the web that allow you to simply upload a video within device art frames, especially free platforms. However, if you have video editing software such as Adobe After Effects, you could import images and videos and create this yourself; albeit added cost and time against the earlier option.

Despite the above, I've managed to utilise Google's Device Art Generator page to extract the device frames they offer quite easily. All you need to do is create a solid background colour in Adobe Photoshop (as an example), say bright green, followed by uploading this to the generator. Download the image generated with the device art applied with the solid fill colour and then use the Magic Wand tool in Photoshop and simply delete the solid colour. With this in mind, the next course of action is to simply insert the video using After Effects in the transparent space now available. This is even a bit overkill, as you only need to overlay the video within the screen dimensions of the generated screenshot from Google, yet this gives you an idea of how you could achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up writing an app to do that:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mobilej.recapp

It works completely on the device - no plugin or desktop version yet. It needs Android 7.0+

I'm the author of the app - so sorry for referring to my own app.